# Using Homogeneous Coordinates in Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, singularity

Recently, I asked a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174200/using-ndsolve-on-the-painlev%C3%A9-equations) on the Mathematica Stack Exchange website regarding the use of homogeneous coordinates in differential equations.

The question is about extending the interval of existence in differential equations using homogeneous coordinates. A prototypical example is the initial value problem for the tangent function.
$$\begin{cases} y'=1+y^2, \\ y(0)=0,  \end{cases}$$
with the corresponding interval of existence being $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Identifying $y$ with a coordinate on the projective line, via $y=y_1/y_2$, results in the underdetermined system
$$\begin{cases} y_1'y_2-y_1y_2'=y_2^2 \left[1+ \left(\dfrac{y_1}{y_2} \right)^2 \right] ,\\ \dfrac{y_1(0)}{y_2(0)}=0. \end{cases} $$
Adding the normalization condition $y_1y_1'+y_2y_2'=0$ (which is a consequence of fixing $y_1^2+y_2^2$), and using the initial conditions $y_1(0)=0,y_2(0)=1$ results in a solvable system, with **global** solutions  $y_1(t)=\sin(t),y_2(t)=\cos(t)$. Thus it can be said that the interval of existence now is the entire real line!

---

I was trying to see how far I can extend this method. In the link above, for instance, I showed that it works (at least numerically) for the $\sec$-$\tan$ system
$$\begin{cases} u'=uv \\ v'=u^2, \\ u(0)=1, \\ v(0)=0. \end{cases} $$

However, with other systems such as the first Painlevé equation
$$\begin{cases} u'=v, \\ v'=6u^2+t, \end{cases} $$
the numerical integrator appears to get stuck at the first pole.

---

**My questions:** Is there a way to employ homogeneous coordinates in order to extend the interval of existence in the case of the first Painlevé equation? More generally, what about systems $ \dot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{f}(t,\mathbf{x})$ with the *Painlevé property* (where all spontaneous singularities are poles)? If so, I'd greatly appreciate some details. I'm not asking for the code here, just the appropriate mathematical formulation.

Thank you!